# Cant get Observable of string value (angular2/typescript)

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a function that gets a list of objects and POSTs it to an api.

The function returns Observable since who ever calls it expects to get a string back from it based on the api response.

If the response is good I want to return a certain string and if it is error I want to send a different string.

This is my function that returns a string:

```
public sendUpdate(updatedList: Cars[]): Observable<string> {
return this._myService.updateListNewOrder(updatedList)
  .map(response => "The POST worked successfully") 
  .catch(error => Observable.of("An Error occurred"));
}
```

So now I want to call this function and get the string in my component.ts:

```
messageToDisplay: string;

  public updateList() {
      this._myService.sendUpdate(this.listToUpdate).subscribe(
        res => this.messageToDisplay = res, // onNext
        error => this.messageToDisplay = error // onError
    );
    }
```

but this is not working...I don't get errors. It is just that the messageToDisplay is staying undefined.

Does anyone see the problem?

Thanks!

If you need it, this is updateListNewOrder(...):

```
public updateListNewOrder(newOrderedList: string[]): Observable<ServerResponse> {
    let apiURL = "my/api/url";
    return this.http.post(apiURL, JSON.stringify(newOrderedList), { headers: this.defaultHeaders() }
    );
  }
```

Comment: Try changing your Observable.of to Observable.throw. From the rxjs docs: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/throw.md

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I reproduced your logic here with my own functions and everything worked fine. Your `sendUpdate` method seems to be correct as well as the `subscribe` function. So, the RxJS logic is ok for me. The problem might be in another peace of code that isn't exposed.

The only issue I found out was the type of the `updateListNewOrder`. It should be `Observable<Response>` instead of `Observable<ServerResponse>` if you are using the `@angular/http` module.